# ajax url gives 403 using a specific word "Altar " or "altar" other urls works fine

Tags: php, ajax, http-status-code-404

A url I am sending to a php file using ajax as a GET is giving me a 403 error when I use the word "Altar " or "altar " followed by a space.  Its a church site, so of course they are going to use this word.

The code works perfectly fine until I use that word in the parameters.  This for example works perfectly fine, even with the url inside and special chars, and a single quote:

ad2calendar.php?ajax=1&u=testuser&d=2013-11-30&s=1&iurl=altar.jpg&eEvent=%3Ca%20href%3D'someurl.com'%20title%3D%22Phony%20URL%22%20%3EA%20Phony%20URL%3C%2Fa%3E%0ASome%20special%20chars%20!%40%26%5E%25%23%24(%23%40%22%22&notes=test&eTitle=Test&y=2013&m=11

But this gives me a 403 because it contains the word "Altar " with a space.

ad2calendar.php?ajax=1&u=testuser&d=2013-11-30&s=1&iurl=&eEvent=Altar%20&notes=test&eTitle=Test&y=2013&m=11

Any thoughts on why a simple word like this could break the URL causing a 403?

My own troubleshooting has discovered the 403 is from a higher directory than that which the php file exists( the php is in a password protected directory ).  I am thinking this may be due to some character encoding issue as I changed the files to UTF-8 recently but it seems to work fine otherwise.  Tried with a blank .htaccess file, so there is no mod_rewrites, using encodeURIComponent on the form fields.  The script is in no way checking for this character combination and redirecting.

I have php strict error reporting on, and no php errors are thrown, nor javascript errors. The only errors I seem to get are related to the 403 page being displayed in the result div, for the ajax response as the 403 page uses resources not in that directory location.

The code itself is pretty complex, so I cannot really start posting all the bits.  Just looking for some directions to troubleshoot further.  Honestly I am going to put in a hack just for this word soon.

Even stranger I was able to use this word a month or 2 ago, but if I roll back my code to that point the error persists.

From my Raw Access Logs, first contains "Altar" and gives 200, second contains "Altar " with a trailing space and gives 403.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [11/Nov/2013:12:35:22 -0500] "GET /ad2calendar.php?ajax=1&u=testuser&d=2013-11-30&s=0&iurl=&eEvent=Altar&notes=&eTitle=&y=2013&m=11 HTTP/1.1" 200 20102 "http://XXXXX/ad2events.php" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [11/Nov/2013:12:35:29 -0500] "GET /ad2calendar.php?ajax=1&u=testuser&d=2013-11-30&s=1&iurl=&eEvent=Altar%20&notes=&eTitle=&y=2013&m=11 HTTP/1.1" 403 1098 "http://XXXXX/ad2events.php" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"
```

Discovered the text "script" in the angle brackets will also give the 403. Example:

```
<script > alert("I am Bad"); </script >
```

The above gives the 403 error.  This confirms there is some security feature or encode issue which is causing this.

Comment: +1 for having the discipline to be able to test with a previous version of the code.... just saying.

Comment: is it just `altar` that gives a 404? What about `ltar` or, er, `aaltar`?

Comment: "ltar " gives the 404, "aaltar " works, I tried some other variations, it is possible some other odd word causes this, which is my primary concern

Comment: What error appears in the web server's log? If you're using apache on ubuntu, you can ``tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`` while reproducing the error.

Comment: check `mod_rewrite` rules in `.htaccess` or server config file ?

Comment: It *sounds* to me either a `mod_rewrite` rule is looking for and redirecting based on that value, or else the script is..

Comment: There is no mod_rewrite rules at all in the .htaccess.  Should there be one to prevent this behavior?  The site is on shared hosting so the server config, I do not believe, is accessible but is most likely default.  Will look into this a bit further.

Comment: Is your host using any form of SQL Injection protection on this server?  Makes me wonder if something is supposed to be blocking the word alter but is instead blocking altar.

Comment: 403 is an access forbidden error, so the clue will most probably be in your apache logs, unless your script is generating the error.

Comment: 404 or 403?  It's not clear whether or not you're getting both, or just the 403 and typo'd it as 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're describing sounds like the action of a badly written [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) rule — possibly one that's trying to prevent injected SQL from containing commands such as `ALTER TABLE`, but with the crucial word in the rule spelled incorrectly (!). Please contact your web host for details.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only explanation I could come up with as well.  Will discuss this matter with my web host.  I actually went in and set the user permissions for the SQL to allow alter for this user, which should thus allow Alter Table, but maybe not if a higher level on the host itself has this misspelled in a rule.  I will mention, there is another database for a image slide show running on this same site, which allows this word without issue, but is using an entirely different php/sql code.

Comment: Added the raw access log entries for two requests above.  Seems strange one of these would pass a mod_security and one would not and "Alter ", which is the SQL keyword, will pass.

Comment: It occurs to me that the first request doesn't contain a space. Do you get the same result with a word other than "Altar"?

Comment: I am unable to get this to fail, with any other words I have tried, other then noted above, "ltar " with trailing space will fail as well, "tar " succeeds.

Comment: Weird! Like I said, though, talk to your web host. This is almost certainly something they're doing.

Comment: Yes, I agree very weird.  Even if I use a long string of text with the word "Altar " thrown in somewhere, it fails. Example "This is some test words blah blah Altar blah blah blah. Some more text." - fails.

Comment: Since I am on a shared hosting, I was not seeing any mod_security errors, nor did I have access to the settings or even the ability to verify mod_security was running.  Some mod_security rules were disabled on contacting my host and this issue has been checked as resolved.

Comment: In retrospect: Perhaps it wasn't about `ALTAR TABLE` (sic) at all - maybe they were trying to prevent the `tar` command from being passed into a script! Still silly, anyway.